# how to get full list of keys from a collection in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How do I get a list of all the keys used in a mongodb collection?

I'm trying to create a csv file in python using the following:

```
userAgentProp_list = []
# userAgentProp is a set of user ids
# userColl is a mongodb collection
for user in userAgentProp:
    userAgentProp_list.append(userColl.find_one({"_id":user}))

with open('userWtihAgentProp.csv','w+') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,userAgentProp_list[0].keys())
    w.writeheader()
    for user in userAgentProp_list:
        # del row['_id']
        w.writerow(user)
```

but I keep getting an error:

```
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames
```

I think this is because `userAgentProp_list[0]` doesn't have all the same fields as the other documents in the collection.

How can I get a list of the all the keys used in the collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've come up with a solution.  I'd love someone with more experience to tell me if this is correct and/or could be done better/more efficiently.

```
def getCollectionKeys(collection):
    """Get a set of keys from a collection"""
    keys_list = []
    collection_list = collection.find()
    for document in collection_list:
        for field in document.keys():
            keys_list.append(field)
    keys_set =  set(keys_list)
    return keys_set
```